# O(1) mapping in Qt?

Tags: c++, database, qt, database-design, architecture

If I have some names like "jenny" "kevin" "miki" ... And each of them have a corresponding QWidget to display their info. Is it possible to have a O(1) mapping from name to QWidget?

Aka, given a name is it possible to fetch its corresponding QWidget in constant time?

(I am doing a central data display app where each person will send me a package includes his name and gps location repeatedly. I need to update his corresponding display widget. Is it possible to do each updating in O(1) time?)

Comment: [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) lookups are `O(1)` at fastest and `O(N)` at slowest (if there are hash collisions)

Comment: This one seems to organize the content in buckets. But is there any true O(1) alternative? Sorry I am new to datastructure.

Comment: That is the best you are going to get in terms of lookups. If you can find a container that promises `O(1)` lookups at all times, you will become very famous :) The problem is that you cannot have a [perfect hashing function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Perfect_hash_function) unless you know all the keys ahead of time, so you cannot prevent the possibility of collisions.

Comment: If the names don't need to be defined runtime but can be fixed on compilation instead, you can create an enumeration of the names and store the widgets in an array.

Comment: The only "true" alternative is O(log N). But why bother?

Comment: Since they send data repeatedly.  if can you send data back for them to send along with future packages then you can get O(1) lookup thereafter by just sending them their widget ID.

Comment: @rpattiso, if there id is 1 2 3 4 5... I can still use array. But if their id is like 1 2 3 99999 5... What can I do?

Comment: Hash works O(1) in 99% cases. And even O(N) is not really bad, if N < 1 mln. So what's the problem?

Comment: The thing is that the frequency of receiving package could be very very high.

Comment: CPU internal frequency is typically _much_ higher than any peripheral hardware I/O. Given that N is small, there's nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hash tables do have O(1) lookup in the best case: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table

If you want that in Qt you can try QHash.
http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/qhash.html

To insert a value is easy as:

```
hash["jenny"] = myWidget;
```

and to lookup:

```
QWidget myWidget = hash["jenny"];
```

You can see the algorithm complexity of the Qt containers here: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-5.4/containers.html#algorithmic-complexity